# Inefficient Random Dice Roll in Python/Jython

Tags: python, jython

As I learn Python (Specifically Jython, if the difference is important here) I'm writing a simple terminal game that uses skills and dice rolls based on the level of those skills to determine success/fail at an attempted action. I hope to use this code eventually in a larger game project.

Under a stress test, the code uses .5GB of ram and seems to take quite a while to get a result (~50 seconds). It could just be that the task is really that intensive but as a noob I'm betting I'm just doing things inefficiently. Could anyone give some tips on both:

- how to improve the efficiency of this code
- and how to write this code in a more pythonic way?

  ```
  import random

  def DiceRoll(maxNum=100,dice=2,minNum=0):
    return sum(random.randint(minNum,maxNum) for i in xrange(dice))

  def RollSuccess(max):
    x = DiceRoll()
    if(x <= (max/10)):
      return 2
    elif(x <= max):
      return 1
    elif(x >= 100-(100-max)/10):
      return -1
    return 0

  def RollTesting(skill=50,rolls=10000000):
    cfail = 0
    fail = 0
    success = 0
    csuccess = 0
    for i in range(rolls+1):
      roll = RollSuccess(skill)
      if(roll == -1):
        cfail = cfail + 1
      elif(roll == 0):
        fail = fail + 1
      elif(roll == 1):
        success = success + 1
      else:
        csuccess = csuccess + 1
    print "CFails: %.4f. Fails: %.4f. Successes: %.4f. CSuccesses: %.4f." % (float(cfail)/float(rolls), float(fail)/float(rolls), float(success)/float(rolls), float(csuccess)/float(rolls))

  RollTesting()
  ```

EDIT - Here's my code now:

```
from random import random

def DiceRoll():
   return 50 * (random() + random())

def RollSuccess(suclim):
  x = DiceRoll()
  if(x <= (suclim/10)):
    return 2
  elif(x <= suclim):
    return 1
  elif(x >= 90-suclim/10):
    return -1
  return 0

def RollTesting(skill=50,rolls=10000000):
  from time import clock
  start = clock()
  cfail = fail = success = csuccess = 0.0
  for _ in xrange(rolls):
    roll = RollSuccess(skill)
    if(roll == -1):
      cfail += 1
    elif(roll == 0):
      fail += 1
    elif(roll == 1):
      success += 1
    else:
      csuccess += 1
  stop = clock()
  print "Last time this statement was manually updated, DiceRoll and RollSuccess totaled 12 LOC."
  print "It took %.3f seconds to do %d dice rolls and calculate their success." % (stop-start,rolls)
  print "At skill level %d, the distribution is as follows" % (skill)
  print "CFails: %.4f. Fails: %.4f. Successes: %.4f. CSuccesses: %.4f." % (cfail/rolls, fail/rolls, success/rolls, csuccess/rolls)

RollTesting(50)
```

And the output:

```
Last time this statement was manually updated, DiceRoll and RollSuccess totaled 12 LOC.
It took 6.558 seconds to do 10000000 dice rolls and calculate their success.
At skill level 50, the distribution is as follows
CFails: 0.0450. Fails: 0.4548. Successes: 0.4952. CSuccesses: 0.0050.
```

Noticeably this isn't equivalent because I changed the random calculation enough to be noticeably different output (the original was supposed to be 0-100, but I forgot to divide by the amount of dice). The mem usage looks to be ~.2GB now. Also the previous implementation couldn't do 100mil tests, I've ran this one at up to 1bil tests (it took 8 minutes, and the mem usage doesn't seem significantly different).

Comment: Questions where you have working code, but are seeking to improve it, are more suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @HenryKeiter would it be more appropriate to cross-post this, or close this one before posting there?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why are you doing `for i in range(rolls+1)` instead of just `range(rolls)`? Think about it in the case where rolls is just 2: `range(2+1)` is going to return `[0, 1, 2]`, which is one too many.

Comment: @abarnert for some reason I thought range() was exclusive on the upper bound. In regards to being off-topic, I seem to be unable to delete now that answers have been posted. Should I just select an answer and repost in CodeReview?

Comment: @NichDel: `range` is exclusive in the upper bound, but inclusive in the lower. That's why `range(2+1)` returns `[0, 1, 2]`—it includes the `0`, but not the `2+1`.

Comment: @NichDel: Meanwhile, you don't need to delete; better to wait for 5 editors to agree that it should be closed and migrated than to do it yourself preemptively. Meanwhile, you can accept an answer if you think anything actually solves your problem, or just upvote the one(s) that are helpful and don't accept anything if you still need more help. Just put a link to this question in your Code Review question, and vice-versa, and if someone thinks it needs cleaning up, they'll do it.

Comment: One more thing: What platform are you on, and how are you determining memory usage? On a quick test on my Mac, almost _any_ Jython program drives the VM up to 200MB immediately, so if switching from `xrange` to `range` cut your memory from 0.5GB to half that, that may mean it's actually completely eliminated the problem.

Comment: @abarnet I'm on Manjaro Linux, I'm measuring mem usage just by watching my mem monitor in my tray. Not exactly the most precise measurement, I suppose.

Comment: @NichDel: Try running a simple Jython program that just loops around `j = i; i = j + i` or something and see how much memory it uses. If it's in the same ballpark as your current program, you definitely don't have a memory problem. That may not be as rigorous a proof as possible, but it has the obvious benefit of simplicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing 10 million loops. Just the looping costs are probably 10% of your total time. Then, if the whole loop doesn't fit into cache at once, it may slow things down even more.

Is there a way to avoid doing all those loops in Python? Yes, you can do them in Java.

The obvious way to do that is to actually write and call Java code. But you don't have to do that.

---

A list comprehension, or a generator expression driven by a native builtin, will also do the looping in Java. So, on top of being more compact and simpler, this should also be faster:

```
attempts = (RollSuccess(skill) for i in xrange(rolls))
counts = collections.Counter(attempts)
cfail, fail, success, csuccess = counts[-1], counts[0], counts[1], counts[2]
```

Unfortunately, while this does seem to be faster in Jython 2.7b1, it's actually slower in 2.5.2.

---

Another way to speed up loops is to use a vectorization library. Unfortunately, I don't know what Jython people use for this, but in CPython with `numpy`, it looks something like this:

```
def DiceRolls(count, maxNum=100, dice=2, minNum=0):
    return sum(np.random.random_integers(minNum, maxNum, count) for die in range(dice))

def RollTesting(skill=50, rolls=10000000):
    dicerolls = DiceRolls(rolls)
    csuccess = np.count_nonzero(dicerolls <= skill/10)
    success = np.count_nonzero((dicerolls > skill/10) & (dicerolls <= skill))
    fail = np.count_nonzero((dicerolls > skill) & (dicerolls <= 100-(100-skill)/10))
    cfail = np.count_nonzero((dicerolls > 100-(100-skill)/10)
```

This speeds things up by a factor of about 8.

I suspect that in Jython things aren't nearly as nice as with `numpy`, and you're expected to import Java libraries like the Apache Commons numerics or PColt and figure out the Java-vs.-Python issues yourself… but better to search and/or ask than to assume.

---

Finally, you may want to use a different interpreter. CPython 2.5 or 2.7 doesn't seem to be much different from Jython 2.5 here, but it *does* mean you can use `numpy` to get an 8x improvement. PyPy 2.0, meanwhile, is 11x faster, with no changes.

Even if you need to do your main program in Jython, if you've got something slow enough to dwarf the cost of starting a new process, you can move it to a separate script that you run via `subprocess`. For example:

subscript.py:

```
# ... everything up to the RollTesting's last line
    return csuccess, success, fail, cfail

skill = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 50
rolls = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) > 2 else 10000000
csuccess, success, fail, cfail = RollTesting(skill, rolls)
print csuccess
print success
print fail
print cfail
```

mainscript.py:

```
def RollTesting(skill, rolls):
    results = subprocess32.check_output(['pypy', 'subscript.py', 
                                         str(skill), str(rolls)])
    csuccess, success, fail, cfail = (int(line.rstrip()) for line in results.splitlines())
    print "CFails: %.4f. Fails: %.4f. Successes: %.4f. CSuccesses: %.4f." % (float(cfail)/float(rolls), float(fail)/float(rolls), float(success)/float(rolls), float(csuccess)/float(rolls))
```

(I used the [`subprocess32`](http://code.google.com/p/python-subprocess32/) module to get the backport of `check_output`, which isn't available in Python 2.5, Jython or otherwise. You could also just [borrow the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/subprocess.py#l544) for `check_output` from 2.7's implementation.)

Note that Jython 2.5.2 has some serious bugs in `subprocess` (which will be fixed in 2.5.3 and 2.7.0, but that doesn't help you today). But fortunately, they don't affect this code.

In a quick test, the overhead (mostly spawning a new interpreter process, but there's also marshalling the parameters and results, etc.) added more than 10% to the cost, meaning I only got a 9x improvement instead of 11x. And that will be a little worse on Windows. But not enough to negate the benefits for any script that's taking on the order of a minute to run.

---

Finally, if you're doing more complicated stuff, you can use [execnet](http://codespeak.net/execnet/), which wraps up Jython<->CPython<->PyPy to let you use whatever's best in each part of the code without having to do all that explicit `subprocess` stuff.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help with all this (even if this post wasn't well suited for this particular forum). While all the other posts were very helpful, you were helpful beyond just your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one thing, use [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of [`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).  `range` allocates an array with an element  for each of the 10 million digits whereas `xrange` creates a generator.  That's going to help out memory a bunch, and probably speed too.

Comment: Thanks! That halved the RAM usage. It seemed like it to a few seconds longer though, which could easily be a fluke.

Answer (score 1):

All those calls to `float()` can be cut by defining those local variables in `RollTesting()` as `0.0`.  `0` is an `int` constant, `0.0` is a `float` constant.  If there's even one `float` involved in any arithmetic operation, another `float` is returned.

Second, you forgot to change that `range()` in `RollTesting()` to `xrange()`.

Third, Python has the usual `+=`, `*=`, `-=`, etc. operators, so `fail = fail + 1` becomes `fail += 1`.  Python doesn't have `--` or `++`, though.

Lastly, you don't need parentheses in `if` statements.

Comment: Most of this (except for the memory usage) may not affect performance much… but it's all very good advice to making the program simpler and more Pythonic.

Comment: As abarnert said, this post didn't help with my efficiency much, but after applying your suggestions it does look much cleaner and easier to read. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about efficiency, use a profiler. Here's 100,000 rolls:

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scratch
CFails: 0.5522. Fails: 0.3175. Successes: 0.1285. CSuccesses: 0.0019.
         1653219 function calls in 5.433 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.433    5.433 <string>:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cp437.py:18(encode)
   200002    0.806    0.000    2.526    0.000 random.py:165(randrange)
   200002    0.613    0.000    3.139    0.000 random.py:210(randint)
   200002    1.034    0.000    1.720    0.000 random.py:216(_randbelow)
        1    0.181    0.181    5.433    5.433 scratch.py:17(RollTesting)
   100001    0.371    0.000    4.864    0.000 scratch.py:4(DiceRoll)
   300003    0.769    0.000    3.908    0.000 scratch.py:5(<genexpr>)
   100001    0.388    0.000    5.251    0.000 scratch.py:7(RollSuccess)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method charmap_encode}
        1    0.000    0.000    5.433    5.433 {built-in method exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method print}
   100001    0.585    0.000    4.493    0.000 {built-in method sum}
   200002    0.269    0.000    0.269    0.000 {method 'bit_length' of 'int' obje
cts}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Prof
iler' objects}
   253196    0.417    0.000    0.417    0.000 {method 'getrandbits' of '_random.
Random' objects}
```

Obviously this code is slightly different because I am running in Python 3, but you should be able to see that you spend most of your time in various random.py functions, in summing, and in the generator expression. This is basically where you would expect to spend your time, really, but can we optimize this further?

Currently DiceRoll generates two random numbers and adds them together. This is an approximation of a normal distribution. Why bother actually rolling the dice? 2d100 is a normal distribution with an average of 101 and a standard deviation of 40.82. (Since these dice actually go from 0 to 99, we can take a couple of points off.)

```
def DiceRoll2():
  return int(random.normalvariate(99, 40.82))
```

Use the built-in function for the job.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('scratch.DiceRoll()', 'import scratch')
7.253364044871624

>>> timeit.timeit('scratch.DiceRoll2()', 'import scratch')
1.8604163378306566
```

Here's the profiler using DiceRoll2 to run 100,000 rolls:

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scratch
CFails: 0.5408. Fails: 0.3404. Successes: 0.1079. CSuccesses: 0.0108.
         710724 function calls in 2.275 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.275    2.275 <string>:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cp437.py:18(encode)
   100001    0.819    0.000    1.393    0.000 random.py:354(normalvariate)
   100001    0.361    0.000    2.094    0.000 scratch.py:10(RollSuccess)
        1    0.180    0.180    2.275    2.275 scratch.py:20(RollTesting)
   100001    0.340    0.000    1.733    0.000 scratch.py:7(DiceRoll2)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method charmap_encode}
        1    0.000    0.000    2.275    2.275 {built-in method exec}
   136904    0.203    0.000    0.203    0.000 {built-in method log}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method print}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
   273808    0.371    0.000    0.371    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
```

This halved the time.

If the majority of your die rolls will be one specific type of roll, you should probably just use the random function that generates the specific distribution you'll get for that roll.

Comment: Hold on… adding two dice is an _approximation of_ a normal distribution, and in general not the same approximation as rounding an actual normal distribution. And definitely not the same as flooring a normal distribution, which is going to give you a mean of 98.5 instead of 99 in this case.

Comment: The roll isn't being exposed to the player in any case -- all they see is the distribution of successes and failures, which are not finely-grained. Nor is it the point -- as you point out, the purpose of rolling dice is to approximate a normal distribution of results! The implementation goal isn't to generate two random numbers, it's to provide approximately normal resolutions to skill challenges. If efficiency is a concern, we should examine cheaper approaches to those resolutions that also provide approximately normal results, no?

Comment: Thank you. I ended up changing to (50 * (random() + random())) [the original code was supposed to be 0-100 but I forgot a /2] which is not exactly what you suggested but still seems much faster than my original formulation.

Comment: @llb: Sure, if you're, say, designing a new computer RPG from scratch, there's no reason to use XdY instead of the distribution you actually want. But if you're implementing a pen&paper RPG, that's a different story. If you want to simulate the odds of a random AD&D 1st-level fighter killing a random orc, you need actual 3d6, not a distribution close to 3d6, right? Meanwhile, as I mentioned, your distribution doesn't even have the same mean as the one the OP used, so it's not a great substitute.